# Quick transfer from Concourse B to Concourse A for connecting flight

Tags: dxb, connecting-flights

I and my wife (both aged above 60) will be flying from Dallas to Kolkata through Dubai airport. EK 222 will probably arrive at Concourse B and the connecting flight EK 572 will leave from Concourse A--both in Terminal 3. But I have only 1 hour to board the connecting flight.

Please give me step by step directions to reach the departing gate very quickly.

By the way, may I use e-boarding pass facility to quicken the process ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a legal connection, but extremely tight. See https://www.aviateworld.com/news/airline-news/emirates-reduces-flight-connection-time-in-dubai/

I would reach out to the airline directly and ask for help and advise, especially if one of you happens to be not as mobile as you used to be.

The emirates web site actually states (under the heading "Inside Emirates Terminal 3" ) https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/emirates-terminal-3/finding-your-way.aspx

> If you are connecting to another flight within 75 minutes, a dedicated
>   team of people will escort you to your gate to make sure you board
>   your next flight in time.

I would contact the airline and verify that you will get help and what exactly the help will do for you.